# R memory management: Difference between warning and error

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

As probably everyone else working with large data and limited memory, I often come across memory problems in R. These problems become manifest in the error message:

```
error: cannot allocate vector of size XYZ
```

which results, as all error messages, in the stop of the workflow; the requested operation has not been carried out.

and sometimes the warning message:

```
Warning: Reached total allocation of 8061Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

which, as all warning messages, does not interrupt the workflow; the requested operation has been carried out.

I wonder,

1. Why do some memory-intense commands result in an error and others in a warning? I.e., what is the technical difference between these two?
2. Are results trustworthy if the warning message has been issued?

Comment: The error is documented [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html): "Error messages beginning `cannot allocate vector of size` indicate a failure to obtain memory, either because the size exceeded the address-space limit for a process or, more likely, because the system was unable to provide the memory." The relevant source for the warning is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/gnuwin32/malloc.c#L1334-L1363). My naive read would be that you should take the warning seriously.

Comment: I believe the warning is issued when R tries to continue and recover from the memory exhaustion (by running the garbage collector). Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101045/r-memory-limit-warning-vs-unable-to-allocate).